# I'm unable to get a simple reCaptcha v2 response to work

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have previously used reCaptcha v1 and all was good until the Google changes a few years ago.  I've now been asked to update a site, and am having some problems even with a simple bit of test code.  The example below is a single index.php page, which traps for 'POST' when a form is submitted.

The reCaptch tick box appears, and allows a tick, but when the form is submitted I only get the 'Check the reCAPTCHA box' response.  It looks like '$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];' is 'blank'. I am using the correct codes, and am getting stats on the reCaptcha admin page, but it is also reporting:

> We detected that your site isn't verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.

What am I missing to verify?

```
<head>

<title>Test Contact Form</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "submit detected..<br>"; 
    $full_name;$email;$subject;$message;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['full_name'])){
            $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
        }if(isset($_POST['email'])){
            $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
            $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        }if(isset($_POST['message'])){
            $message=$_POST['message'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
            echo 'Check the reCAPTCHA box.';
            echo $full_name . "<br>";
            echo $email . "<br>";
            echo $subject . "<br>";
            echo $captcha . "<br>";
            exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "6LemhA8aFAKEDRSKVHsecretVzN7Uv1BVQnpS-LwbjOo";
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
            echo 'You are a robot!';
        }else
        {
            echo "I'd be sending an email to " . $email . "<br>";
            echo "because the secret key" . $secretKey . "<br>";
            echo "and the response " . $captcha . "<br>";
            echo "matched.";
        }
     } ELSE {
?>
    
    
    
    <div class="contact-form">
        <h3>Send me your message v1</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <div class="text-fields">
                <span>Full Name *:</span>
                <input name="full_name" type="text" class="text" value="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="text-fields">
                <span>E-mail *:</span>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="text" value="user@domain.com">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
                <div class="subject-field">
                <span>Subject *:</span>
                <input name="subject" type="text" class="text" value="Your Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="message-field">
                <span>Message *:</span>
                <textarea name="message"> </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LemhA8aFAKEJnoerEbOVLWEkeyYO3CcPo-HEIymP"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You shouldn't share your secret keys of the API.

Comment: Thank you, have changed them - will be destroyed and re-created when I can get this to work anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha v2 Returns JSON Data (As seen on Official site) You should Decode json and then validate it.

```
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$data = array(
    'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET',
    'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
    echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
} else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
    echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
}
```

there is also one problem in your code in " if($response.success==false)" you should write it as "if($response->success==false)"

I will comment after checking with your secrete id (Delete it afterword)

Comment: This is Working my side #with my site key and secrate key ##  modify it according to you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you have an extra `</div>` after `<div class="clearfix"> </div>` – If you remove it, your code will probably work.

The extra closing div tag makes the browser believe that you're closing `<div class="contact-form">` and since the `<form>` tag is inside of that, it tries fix your HTML and close that as well. However, that means that the remaining fields (`subject`, `message`) and reCAPTCHA are placed outside the `<form>`. reCAPTCHA only sets `g-recaptcha-response` if it's actually inside a `<form>`, no matter if the user successfully completes it or not.

**An additional adjustment**

You also need to decode the JSON returned from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify like so:

```
$response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
    if($response["success"]==false)
```